# ¿Cómo puedo iterar objetos con nombres sucesivos en Python?

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo por ejemplo 2 listas en Python:

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3]
lista_2 = [4,5,6]
```

Quisiera crear un bucle que itere de la siguiente manera, y me imprima en pantalla todas las listas:

```
for i in [1,2]:
  print(lista_ + i)
```

No me funciona este último trozo de código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer no es posible con python, debido a que tienes dos estructuras diferentes, una es una variable que se identifica con el valor que tu le has asignado, en este caso

```
lista_1=[]
lista_2=[]
```

Mientras que los otros son valores que no tienen identificador

```
[1,2]
```

Recuerda que cuando creas una variable del tipo

```
name = value
```

El nombre de la variable **name** se convierte en un identificador que no puede ser modificado a la hora de ejecución, mientras que el valor **value** se mantiene como el valor asignado al identificador **name**,dicho de otra manera, el nombre de las variables generan un espacio de memoria con el valor de la variable, puedes leer mas sobre eso [aquí](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/c-api/memory.html).

Ahora, para solucionar tu duda tienes varios caminos que puede seguir.

---

### Unión de listas

Para este caso, puedes tomar las dos listas separadas y unirlas al momento que hacer tu bucle for, como se muestra a continuación.

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3]
lista_2 = [4,5,6]

for i in [lista_1+lista_2]:
   print(i)
```

Con lo cual tendras una salida de datos como la siguiente

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

### Uso de diccionarios

Al usar diccionarios si puedes unir las salidas considerando que un diccionario es una variable de clave valor tipo json, puedes unir la salida como si fueran variables, por ejemplo

```
myDic = {"lista_1":[1,2,3], "lista_2":[4,5,6]}
for i in myDic:
    print(myDic[i])
```

Con lo cual obtendrias una salida como la siguiente.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Bueno, posible sí es. De hecho, el obtener dinámicamente una variable a partir de una string que contenga el nombre de esa variable, es algo muy común en la metaprogramación. Eso nada tiene que ver con la gestión de memoria... Pero sí, definitivamente es mejor tener diccionarios en estos casos.

Comment: En efecto, si nos basamos en la metaprogramación es posible hacer la modificación de nombres de variables o de constantes a partir de una variable, sin embargo en terminos generales y usables es poco practico al nivel descrito en la pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo con eso. Pero ten en cuenta que el OP no desea modificar los nombres de las variables, sino solo acceder a ellas dinámicamente, lo cual es perfectamente posible.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres ver las dos listas, con un solo for es suficiente:

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista_2 = ["a","b","c"]

for lista in lista_1,lista_2:
    print(lista)
```

Si lo que quieres es iterar uno a uno los elementos, necesitas de 2 for:

```
for lista in lista_1,lista_2:
    for j in lista:
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo para ilustrar que sí es posible hacer lo que quieres hacer (considerando que el código se está ejecutando en el scope del módulo, o global):

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3]
lista_2 = [4,5,6]

for i in [1, 2]:
  lista_ = globals()[f'lista_{i}']
  print(lista_)
```

Salida:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

A saber: La función `globals()` nos devuelve un diccionario que contiene las variables globales definidas en el scope del módulo.

Esto funciona, sí. Pero a no ser que tengas una muy buena razón para hacer esto, lo ideal en estos casos, tal como ya se te fue indicado en otra respuesta, es tener un diccionario definido por ti, el cual contenga las listas `lista_1` y `lista_2`.